# Unexpected error in KSH

Tags: shell, ksh

First of all I'm a big noob, and I've strated to study KSH.

I have followed some tutorials, and I got up to this code:

```
#!/bin/ksh


print
print "Please enter the type of "
print "back you want done:[ABCD]."

print "A: Daily"
print "B: Weekly"
print "C: Quarterly"
print "D: Special"

print

print -n "Response: "
read response

print

if [[ $response = [Aa] ]]
then
print "Starting daily backup"

elif [[ $response = [Bb] ]]
then
print "starting weekly backup"

elif [[ $response = [Cc] ]]
then
print "starting weekly backup"

elif [[ $response = [Dd] ]]
then
print "starting special backup"
print
print "Please enter the type of "
print "back you want done:[ABCD]."

print "A: Daily"
print "B: Weekly"
print "C: Quarterly"
print "D: Special"

print

print -n "Response: "
read response

print

if [[ $response = [Aa] ]]
then
print "Starting daily backup"

elif [[ $response = [Bb] ]]
then
print "starting weekly backup"

elif [[ $response = [Cc] ]]
then
print "starting weekly backup"

elif [[ $response = [Dd] ]]
then

print "starting daily backup"

print
print "please take out daily tapes."
print "Please put in weekly tapes,"
print -n "and hit 'enter' to continue."
read waiting

print
print "starting weekly backup"

else

print "'$response' is not a valid option."
fi
```

And Now I have an error in:

```
./backup.ksh: line 18: syntax error at line 82: `then' unmatched
```

What is that I'm doing wrong? Do you have any idea?

Also,

```
[someuser@5278752 ~]$ whereis ksh
ksh: /bin/ksh /usr/share/man/man1/ksh.1.gz
```

I'm using redhat.

Comment: Indent your code.  You might figure the problem yourself!

Comment: Sssh.. Don't tell anyone.  (You have only one `fi`.)

Comment: Thanks for the fi tip.
I nedeed another one! :D Have a nice day man.

Comment: @makemesteaks Post the corrected code as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing  'fi' in there.